# Geometry question using tangents and Pythagorus

Tags: geometry

The pic below shows my exercise. BA is a tangent and equal to 12, R = 4.5. I need to find DC and AC.

[image]

The pic below shows what I came up with so far:

I know that AD is 15, since ∢DBA = 90.

What I though to do next is to add BC cause ∢BCD = 90 and i can use Pythagorus, but the calculation dont come up right...please just give me a hint..tnx

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Pythagoras on each of $\triangle BCD$ and $\triangle BCA$ and subtract the equations from each other.

Or you can use the Power of a Point theorem which says that in your picture $(AC) (AD) = (AB)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Using your own picture with joining $BC$.

Do you see that $\triangle BCD$ is inscribed in semi-circle? What can you infer from that? $\angle BCD=90^ \circ$, right?

Now it means $\angle BCD=90^\circ$.

$\therefore$ You can use Pythagoras theorem.

$BC$ is common, you can express $BC^2=BD^2-DC^2$. Also $BC^2=BA^2-CA^2$. Now equate them both.

$9^2-x^2=12^2-(x-15)^2 \implies 81-x^2=144-(x^2+225-30x)$, can you solve this?